# How to login to a website using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

**I am trying to login into alexa.amazon.com** and I can't do it. I have tried many things and this is what I am trying to use now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import re


payload = {
    "username": "MY_EMAIL", 
    "password": "MY_PASSWORD", 
    "appActionToken": "Taken from the login page"
}

session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = "https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?showRmrMe=1&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fpitangui.amazon.com&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_dp_project_dee&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&"

result = session_requests.get(login_url)

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='appActionToken']/@value")))[0]

result = session_requests.post(
    login_url, 
    data = payload, 
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)

url = 'http://alexa.amazon.com/spa/index.html#settings/dialogs'
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at selenium? (not that I know much about it, but it is the go-to package for webpage automatization)

Comment: Ill look into it I guess but it would suck if I had to learn a whole new thing.

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming :)